# Equivalent of 'find' for finding directories in the linux terminal?

Tags: shell, find

Is there a utility like 'find' to instead find directories with a user specified name in the linux/unix terminal (or an option in find that would enable the same thing)?

Comment: `find` can be limited to only printing directories. See the `-type` predicate.

Comment: Use `find . -type d -name "*something*"`, or `-iname "*something*"` if you want case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` for that plus the option `-type d` (`d` = only directory, `f` would return only files).

Use `-name "pattern"` to search case sensitive. `pattern` can contain `*` (any number of unknown characters, including none) or `?` (exactly one arbitrary character).

Use `-iname "pattern"` to search case insensitive.

Example:

```
find /home -type d -iname "public*html"
```

will find `public_html`, `publichtml` or `PublicHtml` anywhere under `/home`

Related:

- [25 simple examples of Linux find command](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-find-command-examples/)
- [35 Practical Examples of Linux Find Command](http://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/)

Comment: The option would not be named 'd' if the objects that it locates are called "folders".  It finds directories.